# Atmosphere: server receives its message

Tags: javascript, atmosphere, atmosphere.js

I have a ManagedService with onMessage function

```
@ManagedService(path = "/atmosphere/formuserpresence/{id}")
public class FormUserPresenceUpdate extends AtmosphereHelper
{

    @Message
    public final void onMessage(final String message) throws IOException
    {
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
        broadcast(FormUserPresenceUpdate.class, "/atmosphere/formuserpresence/" + statusMessage.getId(), returnArrayString);
    }

}
```

And I have client-server communication. Several clients can subscribe to this channel, using their ids. Then, client can send a status, like

message = {
      ident: "uniqId",
      status: "statusMessageValue"
    });

Class FormUserPresenceUpdate stores all received statuses of all clients and send them back via broadcast function as an array as messages (returnArrayString).

The problem is that, whether the clients receive the correct values (the array of messages), the server receives this array also from itself and failed to parse it. So, the question is: what is the solution for this situation? Can I somehow make it so, not to send this array of messages by server itself? Or should I create second channel (I really would not like to do that) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your message as a class and define an decoder for this class;)

```
public class Message {
    private String ident;
    private String status;
    ...

    getter and setter method.

    ...
}
```

Decoder (this will depend on `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`):

```
public class MessageDecoder implements Decoder<String, Message> {

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public Message decode(String s) {
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(s, Message.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And add `decoders = {MessageDecoder.class}` to `@Message`:

```
@Message(decoders = {MessageDecoder.class})
public final void onMessage(final String message) throws IOException
{
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    broadcast(FormUserPresenceUpdate.class, "/atmosphere/formuserpresence/" + statusMessage.getId(), returnArrayString);
}
```

And there is another solution, use `JSONParser` to determine if message can be parsed into Message class or not, if not, let `@Messsage` method return.

Comment: Thanks for working answer. I solved my particular issue replacing the broadcast function with `return message`. In this way all subscribers receive the message, but the server does not, which was fine for me.

Also found one hint here [link](http://atmosphere-framework.2306103.n4.nabble.com/ManagedService-with-Post-tp4657184p4657185.html) where it is said, that if the decoder for the `onMessage` method fails to decode object, this `onMessage` will be skipped. I think, it is worth adding to your post for other users.

Anyway, marked the question as accepted, thank you. :-)